# Audio HTML5 check if all audio elements have fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm building a quiz that uses audio and is marked on the response time of the user so I want all the audio html elements to be fully loaded before the user can start the quiz.

I just need some sort of loop that checks if ALL the audio elements have all the song/audio loaded completely.

I've looked at `readyState` etc but I cant find its use within a loop of all the audio on the page. I would like a javascript or jQuery solution if possible.

I thought something like below would do it but nope:

```
var ready_count = 0;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("question-audio");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
        var item = x[i];
        item.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if (item.readyState == 4) {
            ready_count++;
        }

    }
if(ready_count == x.length){
    //do something
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a jQuery version:

```
function audioReady(){
  return $.when.apply($, $('audio').map(function(){
    var ready = new $.Deferred();
    $(this).one('canplay', ready.resolve);
    return ready.promise();
  }));
}
```

If you don't have jQuery and/or don't care about older browsers:

```
function audioReady(){
  var audio = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('audio'));
  return Promise.all(audio.map(function(el){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      el.addEventListener('canplay', resolve);
    });
  }));
}
```

Either way, you'll be able to use the function as such:

```
audioReady().then(function(){
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that. There's so much to jQuery I still need to get my head around.

Comment: @AnahitDEV most mobile devices will not load/play audio or video until there is direct physical interaction from the user. And even then most will only allow you to play a single piece of audio/video at a time. So the audioReady Promise will not resolve until you have triggered the device to begin loading each audio element on the page when on a mobile device.

Comment: Yes i agree @idbehold. So what is the workaround for this?

Comment: @AnahitDEV there is no workaround. The user would have to physically touch the screen `N` times where `N` is the number of audio elements on the page and where you attempted to play one audio element each time the user touched. Only then would the `audioReady()` promise be resolved.